# Sort multiple lists alphabetically

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, alphabetical-sort

I'd like to use Jquery to sort *multiple* lists alphabetically. I've come across [Alphabetize a list using JS or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209912/alphabetize-a-list-using-js-or-jquery) as a solution for one list. However, it is not applying when I have multiple lists on the same page.

I have 2 lists here, which I would like to be listed alphabetically, but separated into 2 lists. I don't want them combined together into 1 list.

```
<div class="alphabet">
<b>Fruit</b>
<ul>
<li>Apple</li>
<li>Orange</li>
<li>Banana</li>
</ul>    
<b>Vegetables</b>
<ul>
<li>Lettuce</li>
<li>Carrot</li>
<li>Cucumber</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and this

```
$(".alphabet ul").each(function(){
    $('.alphabet li').sort(function(a, b) {
        var aText = $(a).text(), bText = $(b).text();
        return aText < bText ? -1 : aText > bText ? 1 : 0;
    }).appendTo(this);
});
```

JSfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1efm8aeb/

I believe I'm using .each() wrong, however I am unsure how to fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1efm8aeb/1/

Basically you are missing the fact that once inside the `.each` of `.alphabet ul` selector, you shouldn't select the list items using `.alphabet li` - as it returns all 6 items instead of just the 3.

Instead, you should search for list items only among the children of the `ul` being iterated.

This can be done by modifying the code as:

```
$(".alphabet ul").each(function(){
    $(this).find('li').sort(function(a, b) {
        var aText = $(a).text(), bText = $(b).text();
        return aText < bText ? -1 : aText > bText ? 1 : 0;
    }).appendTo(this);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The explanation makes a lot of sense too. :)