# map ( ) method in jquery, how to alphabetize

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to learn how to alphabetize this list using jQuery. I think I can use map() method, but it does not seem to work because the words aren't separating on each line.

https://jsfiddle.net/TaniaL/jnwr3kfc/
HTML

```
<h2 id="test">List of items</h2>
<button id="alpha">A-Z</button>
<ul id="wordlist">
   <li>The</li>
   <li>Hills</li>
   <li>Are</li>
   <li>Alive</li>
   <li>With</li>
</ul>
```

JQUERY

```
    let array = [];
$('#wordlist li').each(function(){
    let print = $(this).html();
    array.push(print);
    return array
});
console.log(array);




$('button#alpha').on('click', function(){
    array = array.sort();
    let newArray = $.map( array, function(index, item){
        return item + " " + index
    });
    $("#wordlist li").html("<li>" + newArray + "</li>")
    
});
console.log(array);
```

Comment: found answer here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209912/alphabetize-a-list-using-js-or-jquery/36211554](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209912/alphabetize-a-list-using-js-or-jquery/36211554)

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare `innerText` value not `innerHTML`, and you should use [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) if you want to sort an array. And remember to empty your global array every time you try to sort.

```js
let array = [];

function getListContent(){
  array = [];
  $('#wordlist li').each(function(){
    let print = $(this).text();
    array.push(print);
  });
  return array;
}



$('button#alpha').on('click', function(){
    array = getListContent();
    
    array.sort(function(a, b){
        if (a > b) {
        return 1;
        }
        if (b > a) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
    
    
    $("#wordlist li").html('');
    let htmlValue = '';
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      htmlValue += "<li>" + array[i] + "</li>";
    }

    $("#wordlist").html(htmlValue)

    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="test">List of items</h2>
<button id="alpha">A-Z</button>
<ul id="wordlist">
   <li>The</li>
   <li>Hills</li>
   <li>Are</li>
   <li>Alive</li>
   <li>With</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It'd be better to skip the global array entirely!

Comment: Also worth noting that the sort function you've provided is the default behaviour, so while it's useful as a learning aid, it would help to include a comment that it's not necessary

Comment: Oh and if you're naming the function `getSortedArray`, that function should do the sorting. So I recommend either renaming it, or moving the sort

Comment: @FredStark , Working with strings, its' better to make your own sort callback because sometimes it gives unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create an array or create replacement elements

It's much simpler since you can use sort() on a jQuery collection since it is an *array-like* object. Within sort comparator function use `aText.localeCompare(bText)`

After the sort just append the whole sorted collection to the parent list. Since an element can only exist in one place this will loop through the collection appending each one to it's new position

```js
const $list = $("#wordlist")

$('button#alpha').on('click', function(){
   const $items = $list.children().sort(function(a,b){
       return $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text())
   });
   $list.append($items) 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="test">List of items</h2>
<button id="alpha">A-Z</button>
<ul id="wordlist">
   <li>The</li>
   <li>Hills</li>
   <li>Are</li>
   <li>Alive</li>
   <li>With</li>
</ul>
```